# Phonegap Whitelist not working. CLI5.2 Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

My APP is android only I use OSX.

Using the PhoneGap APP (servered in my computer to my phone) everything works perfect!

But since I compiled the APK using the build.phonegap.com It doesnt load external content. Like external javascript or $.post ajax.

I put in the html header:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
       content="default-src *; 
        style-src *; 
        script-src *;">
```

And my config.xml is current like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.foryounetwork.foryougran"  version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name> name </name>
    <description> desc </description>
    <author email="mymail" href="link"> name </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' />
    <gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-whitelist' source='npm' />
    <gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-splashscreen' source='npm' />
    <gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-media'  source='npm' />
    <gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-file'  source='npm' />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" source='npm' />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" /> 
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" /> 
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> 
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" /> 
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" /> 
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" /> 
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> 
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    </widget>
```

So no idea, but its not connecting to external content from app. Probably a whitelist thing, but I have no idea.

Tryed with CLI5.2 and 5.11. I use OSX, I dont use any terminal commands.

Comment: But it is based in example that Phonegap makes.. Where can I find a good example to me base on?

Comment: chenged to this ( I edited the config.xml above) , but external links still doesnt work:

Comment: Sorry. It was late. I must have been looking at another post. Your `config.xml` IS NOT for *Phonegap Build*. You do not use *Phonegap CLI* to make *Phonegap Build* Applications. You have made a common mistake. **READ** [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md), Then, throw out what you have.  Start Here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29

Comment: is your issue resolved?